# bootstrap form-group behaviour small device

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've come across a problem when using form-groups on my forms, especially on sm view I don't like the space between input fields inside form-groups.

Is there an easy solution to make the gap between input-fields inside a form-group div as wide as the space between different form-groups? Check the code & fiddle below.

Any useful hints are welcome! Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
I'm not looking for a CSS solutions, I could do one on my own - I'm looking for a proper bootstrap way :)**

[screenshot with small description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTS9u.png)

http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dc/552/

```
<form id="test" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_name" name="input_name" type="text" placeholder="IMG_0202" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_title">Title</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_title" name="input_title" type="text" placeholder="San Francisco..." class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_size">Size</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_size" name="input_size" type="text" placeholder="900x600" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="select_body">Camera Body</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="select_body" name="select_body" class="form-control">
          <?php select code ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_iso">ISO</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_iso" name="input_iso" type="text" placeholder="100" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="select_lens">Camera Lens</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="select_lens" name="select_lens" class="form-control">
          <?php select code ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_aperture">Aperture</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_aperture" name="input_aperture" type="text" placeholder="F/5.6" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_exposure">Exposure</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_exposure" name="input_exposure" type="text" placeholder="1/1000 sec" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_location">Location</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_location" name="input_location" type="text" placeholder="47.586319, 7.648753" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_createdate">Create date</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="input_createdate" name="input_createdate" type="text" placeholder="1986-04-23 13:37:00" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="submit"></label>
      <div class="btn-group col-md-4 col-xs-12" role="group">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-6 col-xs-6">Insert</button>
        <button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-default col-md-6 col-xs-6">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Use margins. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider one form-group. I think you are trying this

```
  <div class="custom-margin">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="input_name" name="input_name" placeholder="IMG_0202" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="custom-margin">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_title">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="input_title" name="input_title" placeholder="San Francisco..." class="form-control input-md" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
```

In your CSS

```
.custom-margin{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Is there no bootstrap out-of-the-box solution? I'd have built something on my own.

Comment: nope. This is quite  specific to your requirements. Its best to first learn up on CSS, before approaching bootstrap, or you end up with many issues such as these

Answer (score 1):

Add two divs and give 6 or more columns to small screens (depending on how big you want the input fields). Now treat these two divs as two columns that the user will see on his screen and add your required fields in these divs respectively.

**Example**

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_name">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="input_name" name="input_name" type="text" placeholder="IMG_0202" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="input_title">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="input_title" name="input_title" type="text" placeholder="San Francisco..." class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result using your code**
[image: see example]

**Result using the solution code**
[image: see example]